# MYSQL trigger to delete row after it's updated

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, mariadb

I have a table named "Booking" that has 6 columns, id,employer,breakfast,lunch,dinner and canceled.

I want to create a trigger that deletes the row if canceled is updated to '1' (if canceled=1 then row to be deleted).

how can I create the trigger for that in MySQL?

I've heard that it's impossible, so if it really is then i would like other suggestions.

thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Why do you even have the `canceled` column then? Just issue a `DELETE` where the `UPDATE ... SET canceled = 1 ...` is done. Or keep the row, set `canceled` and change the queries reading from the table to filter out canceled bookings. You can also create a view to do that and query that instead of the table.

Comment: This schema is need of a redesign

Comment: write an event that delrtes all the wanted rows an mifnight

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to issue any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE a table from a trigger on that same table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-can-triggers-tables says:

> ...it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

In a before UPDATE trigger, you can only set the values of columns.

As suggested in the comments above, you can then periodically run some code to delete rows where `canceled=1`. But you can't do this in a trigger.